# profit from lottery ticket

Tags: probability

Jessica is playing a game where there are 4 blue markers and 6 red markers in a box. She is going to pick 3 markers without replacement.
If she picks all 3 red markers, she will win a total of 500 dollars. If the first marker she picks is red but not all 3 markers are red, she will win a total of 100 dollars. Under any other outcome, she will win 0 dollars.

**Solution**
The probability of Jessica picking 3 consecutive red markers is: $\left(\frac16\right)$

The probability of Jessica's first marker being red, but not picking 3 consecutive red markers is:
$\left(\frac35\right)-\left(\frac16\right)=\left(\frac{13}{30}\right)$

So i am bit stuck here

**what i think** is it shouldn't be that complex it should be as simple as 
 chance of Jessica's first marker being red=chance of getting red 1 time
i.e P(First marker being red)=$\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)$
can any explain me the probability of Jessica's first marker being red=$\left(\frac{13}{30}\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of first marker red is indeed $\frac35$.  However, the probability you presented is probability of the first marker red AND not all markers red.  Thus the probability of all markers red got subtracted off.

Comment: but the question says they only want first marker red just to win 100 dollar so why should i care to find the second marker red

Comment: Because you might want to keep track of the possibility of winning $500$ dollars.  It is certainly true that you could say once the first marker is red Jessica will win at least $100$ dollars; and if the next two markers are red she will win an additional $400$ dollars.

Answer (score 1):

$P\left(R_{1}R_{2}R_{3}\right)=P\left(R_{1}\right)P\left(R_{2}\mid R_{1}\right)P\left(R_{3}\mid R_{1}R_{2}\right)=\frac{6}{10}\frac{5}{9}\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{6}$

$P\left(R_{1}R_{2}^{c}R_{3}\right)+P\left(R_{1}R_{2}R_{3}^{c}\right)+P\left(R_{1}R_{2}^{c}R_{3}^{c}\right)=P\left(R_{1}\right)-P\left(R_{1}R_{2}R_{3}\right)=\frac{6}{10}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{13}{30}$

Comment: Hey can u please explain these

Comment: $R_1R_2R_3$ stands for: first is red, second is red, third is red. $R_i^c$ for: $i$-th is not red. $P(R_2\mid R_1)$ for: the probability that the second is red under the condition that the first is red. $P(R_3\mid R_1R_2)$ for: the probability that the third is red under condition that the first and second are red.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of choosing 3 consecutive red markers is
6C3 / 10C3 (no. of favourable outcomes= 6C3, total no of outcomes= 10C3)
This evaluates to (1/6).

If you get first marker red, the other markers may or may not be red. If you say they are not all red, you reduce the number of favourable outcomes and decrease the probability (13/30 < 6/10).

For the second part of the problem.
Probability of first marker being red=6/10.
Probability of all three markers being red = 1/6
Probability of first marker being red, but not picking 3 consecutive red markers is: 6/10 - 1/6

Comment: OK, so you mean that we have to subtract the probability of picking 3 consecutive red from the Probability of first marker being red in order to get 100 dollar either we will win 500 dollars

Comment: yes. I assume you have to solve for the expectance / average prize amount using these probabilities